# Does the meaning change if I add "which are" in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> There are factors considered to be more relevant to a person's success in life.

Does the meaning change if I insert "which are" in the sentence?

> There are factors which are considered to be more relevant to a person's success in life.

If it doesn't change,  which would be better in formal writing?

Comment: The meaning does not change.  Either is fine in formal writing.  My personal opinion is that if a word is not necessary, you should not include it, but that's just style.

Comment: Speaking of formal writing style, the passive voice may be an issue. _Who_ considers these factors more important? If the subject can be identified, rewrite the sentence using the active voice.